# How to include user config in the SPARK STEPS in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-emr

I want to take the user input from airflow in json format like this:

```
{"type":"adhoc", "start_date":"2022-01-01", "end_date":"2022-05-01"}
```

and then use the `start_date` and `end_date` in my EmrAddStepsOperator.

```html
step_adder_adhoc = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='step_adder_adhoc',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow_1', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
        do_xcom_push = True,
        steps=SPARK_STEPS_ADHOC
    )
    
    
    SPARK_STEPS_ADHOC = [
    {
        'Name': 'data-pipeline-adhoc-job1',
        'ActionOnFailure': 'TERMINATE_CLUSTER',
        'HadoopJarStep': {
            'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
            'Args': [
                'spark-submit',
                '--deploy-mode',
                'client',
                '--class',
                'jobs.StandardSparkJob',
                'foo.jar',
                --output_path,
                's3://foo/{STARTDATE}-{ENDDATE}
```

I want to insert my `start_date` and `end_date` from the user into {STARTDATE}-{ENDDATE}.
I have tried using `os.environ` to push the variables and then use it in the `SPARK_STEPS_ADHOC` but doesn't work out.

Comment: by saying user input, you mean that in your dag  you defined params with type, start_date and end_date ?